# Unit testing a multi step flow in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have an authorization flow I want to test that involves making a request and obtaining a token, and using the token inside different test methods.

What would be the best way to test this scenario?

Can I run the test methods in a sequence and pass the token as a parameter, or am I taking a wrong approach at testing this?

Comment: Unit tests should test units. Units = methods. In general, the method being tested should have some input and output parameters so that you can compare expected and actual results. Perhaps you are looking for some kind of automation or acceptance tests, not unit ones.

Comment: This recent blogpost of mine might interest you: http://www.vannevel.net/2015/03/21/how-to-unit-test-your-owin-configured-oauth2-implementation/ Basically all you need to do for a "sequential" flow like this is change the assumptions you make in each test's *Arrange* section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood, making a request and obtaining a token is part of test initialization. So you can move that into to the `[TestInitialize]` keep the token as a private field for your test class and use it for your individual test methods.

In short, your unit test will consist of 3 parts.

1. Common stuff which will go into initialize
2. Test method specific condition which will be in beginning of each test case
3. Assert.

One thing to keep in mind, multiple test cases will be executed in parallel and you cannot rely on any inter test case sequence.

Comment: Tests are executed sequentially by default in Visual Studio, they're just not executed in a deterministic order. That is entirely different from parallel execution.

Comment: You are right but what I meant it they can be made to run in parallel on a multicore machine if configured - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/12/01/executing-unit-tests-in-parallel-on-a-multi-cpu-core-machine.aspx hence affecting OP's expectation.